# Ubuntu freezes after sleep

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 on a HP Z230 with an Nvidia NVS 315 video card.
After the system goes to sleep and wakes up again, the screen is black and stays that way. The only way to recover I found is to restart the system.

I figured that this could be a problem with the graphics driver. An NVS card is not really mainstream. So, I downloaded a linux driver from Nvidia (NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-346.59.run). I figured out how to shutdown lightdm (otherwise there was a complaint about a running X server), but then the script complained that the preinstall script did not complete succesfully. I didn't think it was wise to continue. That is where I am stuck.

Any idea if the graphics driver is the problem? Or should I look somewhere else?

Answer (score -1):

That sounds like a similar problem I had when I updated my kernel.
The fix is described in detail [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD).

**The proposed solution - fixing the problem on my computer**

First, make a copy of your xorg.conf

```
sudo cp /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.BAK
```

You may need also to install linux headers first.

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
```

Install fglrx with hardware acceleration

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx xvba-va-driver libva-glx1 libva-egl1 vainfo
```

Generate a fresh xorg.conf before rebooting

```
sudo amdconfig --initial
```

As a result, my problem was solved and the "Sleep Mode" works without problems.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Fair point, I'll extrapolate the necessary information and post it, adding the link as a reference.